# Adding fonts to reportlab in docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, reportlab

I have an application running in 3 separated containers. One for django app, one for postgresql and the third one is for nginx. In my docker-compose file I have volume for static files where I put my font.ttf file. I checked the container and the file is there, however it is not being loaded. Here is the settings for web container:

```
web:
    image: ashowlsky/foodgram:latest
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn foodgram.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./static:/code/static/
      - ./media:/code/media/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

And here is the part of view:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('OS', '/code/static/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'))
```

Part of nginx.conf file for static files:

```
location /static/ {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            autoindex on;
            alias /code/static/;
        }
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: which is your STATIC_ROOT in your django settings? Are you configuring a location for static files in nginx configuration?

Comment: @franciscorode ofc I do. updated post with nginx setup

Comment: i think nginx container need have access to volume, can you check that the file is accessible in /code/static/ inside of your nginx container?

Comment: @franciscorode yes, it is in nginx container in /code/static

Comment: ok, Have you test to assign STATIC_ROOT = ''/code/static" in django settings?

Comment: @franciscorode yes, it returns 500 as well. It can not happen for any other reason than code being unable to locate font.

Comment: yes, it didn't make sense that the problem was nginx when trying to load the file by code, well seen

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting containers for a while I understood that docker was simply using outdated version of an image. In my case the solution was `docker-compose pull`...